# Does achemso no longer support "submitted" BibTeX entry types?

Tags: bibtex, journal-publishing, achemso

Looking through old documentation for `achemso.bst`, I noticed that it (at one time?) supported a `submitted` entry type for articles that have been submitted but not published.  I was unable to find any reference to the `submitted` type in the most recent version of `achemso.bst`, although it does appear to implement `inpress`.  Oddly enough, BibTeX does not complain when a `submitted` entry type is used (the resulting reference lacks the journal name and any mention of being submitted) and it is unclear what code is handling this case at compile time.  Has this feature been removed or was it never even there?  What is the "official" way of handling submitted articles in `achemso`?

P.S.- I wanted to thank Joseph Wright for the `achemso` package, which is excellent and very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original author of `achemso`, Mats Dahlgren, included various non-standard BibTeX entry types in `achemso.bst`. When I took over the package and revised for v2.0 these non-standard types were retained: the last release on this major branch was `2008/04/16 v2.2i`. The bundle was heavily revised in 2010 to properly support submission to the ACS and to address a number of sub-optimal decisions. This included removing several non-standard entry types for BibTeX: `inpress` and  `patent` were retained (they are useful). The first release of the v3.0 branch is dated 2010/04/29. The `submitted` type has not bee included since this release.

Notable, BibTeX will use a 'fall-back' type, `misc`, if the requested entry type is unknown. At the same time, one can use the `misc` type directly and include essentially all details by hand as `howpublished`.

Comment: Perhaps one more for the academia site, but I'd say you should not be referencing 'submitted' articles at all. Until they are accepted they are not available in any form to referees and indeed such references are more-or-less meaningless. If refereeing a paper I'd always comment that such references should be removed.

Comment: Perhaps with hindsight I'd have left the removed entry types in the code, but I'm not altering that now!

Comment: Depends on the field tho. In some other fields, it is quite common (necessary) to cite unpublished works.

Comment: @yo' To some extent, but I suspect you are thinking of areas with preprints (_i.e. we are not talking texts which are completely unavailable to reviewers/readers).

Comment: ACS allows for "submitted for publication" references, but the manuscript of the referenced paper must be included with the submission so that it can be evaluated by reviewers if desired.

Comment: @tarheels Yes, I know: I do reviews for the ACS! However, I'd still comment on this to the editors in such a case: as a reader these things are a right pain.

Comment: No offense intended.  I completely agree that such "non-public" references should be avoided if at all possible, reserved only for papers that are on the cusp of publication (as in my case) if ever.  While your reservations are certainly founded, it is might be helpful to achemso users to document the best practice for including unpublished references, leaving it to editors/reviewers to determine their merit.